# xcode submission app unable to upload

Tags: xcode, app-store

I've got a problem uploading an app on the app store. I have a developer account since this morning.

I've done all the certificate but when I arrive in the organizer, when I click on download dsyms it's said that I've no account (and the upload button is greyed out).

When I click on add account, I see my account

(See the screenshots)

Thanks for your help

[image: no account]

[image: certificate]

Comment: Are you able to sign in to [iTunesConnect](http://itunesconnect.apple.com)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to [iTunesconnet](http://itunesconnect.apple.com/) and sign in there, then create your app details there, remember, you must have to provide the exact version of your app to the iTunesconnect. Then, when everything you done in iTunesconnet, then try to upload your app with your correct distribution profile.

Thanks